# How to create a OCR form using HTML or PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, ocr

I need to create a OCR Form using HTML or PHP. User can take the Print of the Form and Printed form will be Readable via OCR. This form will consist of Radio button and Check Box.

How this form will work?
1) There will be a HTML form with Some Question and Answer Options below. Options will be radio box.
2) User can take print out of this Form, and fill the radio box using pen.
3) Scanned version of printed form will be readable via OCR.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Your question is off-topic for this site as it is unclear what you are asking.  As it stands it is merely a list of requirements.  StackOverflow is not a discussion site or tutorial site, and also not a site where you can ask others to do work for you.

Comment: Also think of alternatives. Why would you have the user create a print-out and then interpreting it via OCR? I'd rather create a useful output directly for the user to download.

Answer (score 0):

Up-to-date OCR systems will process any form you can design. However, it would be rather tricky processing for the forms where OCR coordinates are not fixed and OCR elements design may vary due to different web browsers. 
I'd rather suggest PDF forms, because PDF format guarantees that all the customers  will receive the same printing no matter what platform do they use.